# The entity type <Entity> is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I am developing a fairly basic C# application using Data First Entity Framework Model. All was going well until I added a fifth table to my database and updated my my model from the database. Up I am still able to add, remove update data in all other tables in my database but for some reason I keep running into this issue with the last table that I added to my database. I am using Entity Framework 6x

From all the research that I have done, this seems like a fairly common issue that people run into and I have tried several suggestions including...

- Changing the connection string to ADO.NET connection string
- Removing the entity and updating my EDMX model from the database.
- Connecting the entity to the table in void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) function of context.cs
- Matching the connection strings in APP.config and Web.config.

Nothing seems to have worked so far.

```
//Monies.Context.cs
namespace MoneyManager.DB
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class MoniesEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MoniesEntities()
            : base("name=MoniesEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    }
}
//Expense.cs
namespace MoneyManager.DB
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Expense
    {
        public System.Guid ExpenseId { get; set; }
        public System.Guid VendorId { get; set; }
        public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
        public System.Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
        public System.Guid SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public MoneyManager.DTO.Enums.PaymentMode PaymentMode { get; set; }
        public int PaymentMethod { get; set; }
        public string PaymentDetail { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ExpenseDate { get; set; }
    }
}

//ExpenseRepository.cs
namespace MoneyManager.DB
{
    public class ExpenseRepository
    {

        public static void SaveExpense(DTO.Expense dtoExpense)
        {
            MoniesEntities db = new MoniesEntities();

            MoneyManager.DB.Expense expense = new MoneyManager.DB.Expense();

            expense.Amount = dtoExpense.Amount;
            expense.CategoryId = dtoExpense.CategoryId;
            expense.Comment = dtoExpense.Comment;
            expense.ExpenseDate = dtoExpense.ExpenseDate;
            expense.ExpenseId = dtoExpense.ExpenseId;
            expense.PaymentDetail = dtoExpense.PaymentDetail;
            expense.PaymentMethod = dtoExpense.PaymentMethod;
            expense.PaymentMode = dtoExpense.PaymentMode;
            expense.SubCategoryId = dtoExpense.SubCategoryId;
            expense.UserId = dtoExpense.UserId;
            expense.VendorId = dtoExpense.VendorId;


            db.Expenses.Add(expense);  //This is where I get this error
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

//Connection String

Here is the stack trace

> InvalidOperationException: The entity type Expense is not part of the
>   model for the current context.
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappingsForType(Type
>   entityType) +209
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +51
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +137
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +38    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName) +236
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity) +200
>   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity) +130
>   MoneyManager.DB.ExpenseRepository.SaveExpense(Expense dtoExpense) in
>   c:\MoneyManager\MoneyManager.DB\ExpenseRepository.cs:31
>   MoneyManager.Domain.ExpenseManager.SaveExpense(Expense dtoExpense) in
>   c:\MoneyManager\MoneyManager.Domain\ExpenseManager.cs:13 c:\
>   MoneyManager.Web.ExpenseNew.submitButton_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in MoneyManager\MoneyManager.Web\ExpenseNew.aspx.cs:93
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9782698

Comment: I think  if you have more than one DbConfiguration in the same app-domain, then that is likely to cause issues.

Comment: Hi Sunil, how do I do about determining how many DbConfigurations I have in the same app-domain?

Comment: The really strange part is that this is only happening for the new tables / entities that I adding to my database. I can read and write from and to all other tables successfully

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your OnModelCreating of MoniesEntities class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Expense>().ToTable("Expenses");
}
```

Comment: Sorry that did not work. I am still receiving the same message. Here is what my Context.cs looks like now after adding the suggested code.  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Expense>().ToTable("Expenses");
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

Comment: check your connectionstring and if you can recreate your database.

Comment: The really strange part is that this is only happening for the new tables / entities that I adding to my database. I can read and write from and to all other tables successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but I just encountered this error myself (Database first), with a table that had existed since the start of my project (with some newly added recently) although I think I may have made a change to the table which I later reversed, so that may have been the cause.

**Resolved it by selecting all the models in the .edmx file, deleting the lot, and then right-click and choose "Update model from database".**

For some reason only deleting the problematic model did not do the trick.